# What is the Massacre spell's area of effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

Under the description of the [*massacre*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/massacre/) spell's effect, the area is stated to be a "60-ft. line"; however, under the spell description, it says:

> You unleash a wave of necromantic energy that snuffs out the life force of those in its path. **This wave pulses out from you in a line 5 feet wide and 30 feet long.** [...] If the spell does not kill any creatures, the unreleased necromantic energy violently explodes in the final square of the **60-foot line**

Is there an explanation for the discrepancy between the descriptions of it as a 30-foot line or a 60-foot line? Or is one of those numbers a typo?

What is *massacre*'s area of effect?

Answer (score 5):

The *Horror Adventures* FAQ includes [this entry](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1hf#v5748eaic9v13):

> ***Massacre*: In two places, [*massacre*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/massacre/) says it’s a 60-foot line, but in another, it says it’s a 30-foot line. Which is correct?**
>
> It’s a 60-foot line of death.

In other words, change the *30* in the [*massacre*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/massacre/) spell's description to *60*, and all should be well… for the caster, anyway.

Comment: Maybe the wave is supposed to be 5 ft thick and 30 ft wide?  Otherwise the shape is not much of a wave, considering this is a 9th level spell.

Comment: @MikeQ Honestly, I don't think it matters either way. It's not much of a spell period. Seriously, just take instead *shapechange*, *wish*, or even *wail of the banshee.*